# Paypal adaptive payments: unsupported country code error 580022

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, country-codes

Just reporting this error that has occurred on any paypal response to preapproval requests in the adaptive payments environment since september 17 in the morning (Italy time):

errorId: 580022
domain: PLATFORM
subdomain: Application
severity: Error
category: Application
message: Unsupported country code IT
parameter: Array

Everything worked fine till yesterday.
Post this because the more with the same issue will open a ticket to paypal MTS support, the more chances we'll have to be taken in charge from the tech team.

Comment: Just a note: other three persons have reported the same issue from Italy and France today in the paypal community forum.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue since today. France region

Comment: We are also facing same issue..

Comment: Just received an update from MTS: "our engineering team is now treating this as a Severity 1 blocking issue. That means that the fix will have top priority". As soon as I hear any ETA on the fix, I will let you know asap.

Comment: From 6.45 (italy time) the issue seems to be resolved in Italy.
Will post the confirmation from paypal as soon as it will arrive as an answer to this question in the next hours.

Answer (score 0):

We're received confirmation from Paypal that the issue has been resolved now.
Unfortunately, while the issue has been resolved, as far as we've understood talking with the MTS team, it turned up the light on adaptive payments compliance with PSD2 and SCA (strong customer authentication) new rules from EU. This turns in a probable future impact on adaptive payments integrations.

What they told me is that the communication team is on the go to send details to impacted merchants. The good thing is that they've assured the MTS team that no adaptive accounts will be left alone, a special team instead will help those impacted to find alternative solutions through other APIs.

We'll keep you posted with more comments as soon we'll have some more details on it.